# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't rebuild project even if changes have been made

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a static library and an exe that relies on it. I have already configured the exe project to previously request the build of the library, but even if I change some code, running the exe, or right click and compile the library won't update it. Only re-building it will apply the correct changes.

I have already set the option "On Run, when projects are out of date" to "Always compile" and un-ticked the option "only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" but nothing seems to have effect.

Answer (score 1):

A year and a half late, but maybe this will help somebody.

You have to set a project dependency. I don't have VS 2015, but on VS 2017, under the "Project" menu select "Project Dependencies..."
[Project > Project Dependencies... menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYdUf.png)

- At the top you should see a combo box labeled "Projects", make sure the project that builds your ".exe" is selected.
- Below that, you should see a list of other project(s) to choose from with a checkbox next to each one. Click the project for your static library so that it has a check.
- Click the OK button, you should be done.